# Mesmo com ".AsNoTracking" acontece o erro "cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

```
public class ProcessoOsOperacaoEntity
{
    public int? Id {get; set; }

    public int? IdProcessoOs { get; set; }

    public virtual ProcessoOsEntity ProcessoOs { get; set; }

    public int? IdUsuario { get; set; }

    public virtual UsuarioEntity Usuario { get; set; }

    public int? IdPatrimonio { get; set; }

    public virtual PatrimonioEntity Patrimonio { get; set; }

    public DateTime Inicio { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;     

    public StatusOperacao? Status { get; set; }

    public decimal? Qtde { get; set; } = 0;

    public int? IdReinicio { get; set; }

    public virtual ProcessoOsOperacaoEntity Reinicio { get; set; }
}
```

```
using (var rep = new DataContext())
{
    var op = rep.Operacoes.Where(w => w.IdProcessoOs == _processoOs.Id &&
                            w.IdUsuario == _usuario.Id)
                .OrderByDescending(od => od.Id)
                .FirstOrDefault();

    if (op != null) { if (op.Status != StatusOperacao.Pausa) { op = default; } }

    var operacao = new ProcessoOsOperacaoEntity
    {
        IdProcessoOs = _processoOs?.Id,
        ProcessoOs = _processoOs,

        IdUsuario = _usuario?.Id,
        Usuario = _usuario,

        IdPatrimonio = _patrimonio?.Id,
        Patrimonio = _patrimonio,

        Inicio = DateTime.Now,
        Status = StatusOperacao.Executando,
        Qtde = 0
    };

    rep.Add(operacao);

    if (op != null)
    {
        op.IdReinicio = operacao.Id;
        op.Reinicio = operacao;

        rep.Update(op);
    }

    rep.SaveChanges();
}
```

Recupero um registro do banco e crio um novo. Dentro do antigo tento colocar o registro criado na propriedade reinicio obtendo o erro:

```
The instance of entity type 'ProcessoOsOperacaoEntity' cannot be tracked 
 because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. 
 When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with 
 a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging'
 to see the conflicting key values.
```

Comment: Para você criar uma entidade nova é com `new` do jeito que você está fazendo ainda está ligado no contexto você deve fazer uma consulta simples com `AsNoTrancking()` (`ReadOnly`) e dar um `new` na nova entidade. Se precisa duplicar precisa fazer assim.

Comment: por que você quer adicionar duas vezes a mesma entidade? não entendi

Comment: @VirgilioNovic e @Lucas Não estou tentando duplicar a entidade. Estou pegando a anterior, e nessa anterior estou referenciando o ID da nova. E, já existe um ```new```

Comment: Você não está fazendo certo, você está dando `default` numa entidade anexada e não é assim que se faz!

Comment: Seto default (null) somente se for diferente de pausa e ele entra no código lá embaixo somente se for diferente de null.